# Firestore collection group query stream is not updated

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter with Firebase Firestore for a mobile app. The following collection group stream works and is updated every time a task field is updated.

```dart
Firestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('tasks')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((QuerySnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
  print('task change is triggered');
});
```

When I query the collection group with 'array-contains', the **query works** but a change to a task doesn't update the stream.

```dart
Firestore.instance
    .collectionGroup('tasks')
    .where('assignees', arrayContains: userData.id) // new query line
    .snapshots()
    .listen((QuerySnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
  print('task change is triggered');
});
```

Could you explain the reason for this behavior? And what should I do to get collection group query results in real-time? Are there any indexing settings I should consider?

Comment: Is `userData.id` same data type as elements in `assignees`?

Comment: Yes @ShababbKarim, the query works just as expected when I reload my app. The problem is the stream doesn't get updates.

Comment: Found out what was going on. take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally found what was going on. 
Firebase usually outputs an error message with a URL to set required `Exemptions` in Firebase 'Indexes' section. But there was **no error message** when I was using `collectionGroup().snapshots().listen()`.

Then I called `collectionGroup().getDocuments()` just to see if it's working and an error popped up with an exemption URL. After setting that exemption, `collectionGroup().snapshots().listen()` started to work again!

I thought this tip would be useful for someone.